# How do I add on text on to all product page titles in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to change all of my products to have "store.commoto.com" at the end of their page title. How can I do this is MySQL? What syntax would I use to do this?

I have tried this and it didn't work:

```
UPDATE product_table WHERE page_title = "" SET page_title = "store.commoto"
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with MySQL

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: @dan I disagree.  String concatenation may not be native database operation and therefore it varies by vendor.

Answer (score 1):

use the string concatenation function (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

`update product set page_title = concat(pageTitle, 'store.commoto.com');`

Answer (score 0):

*I think:*

```
Update ProductsTableNameHere SET  Title = concat(Title, ' store.commoto.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
update tablename set title = concat(title,"your text");
```